# WPF Listview - binding a text column to a combobox column selected item

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, combobox, wpf-4.0

I have a Listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FieldMap.SourceTargetFieldMap, Mode=Default}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Source Fields" CellTemplate="{StaticResource sourceFieldsTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Source Values" CellTemplate="{StaticResource =sourceValueTemplate}">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Target Field" CellTemplate="{StaticResource targetFieldTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And I also have cell data templates that these bind to:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="sourceFieldsTemplate">
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbSourceField" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SourceField, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="FieldName" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceFieldValues}" Width="120" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="sourceValueTemplate">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbSourceValue" Margin="5,0,0,0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbSourceField, Path=SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding Path=FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Width="115" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="targetFieldTemplate">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbTargetField" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=TargetField}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="155" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I want to do is, bind the Source Value textbox field to the selected item of the SourceFields combobox.  So when an item is selected from the sourcefield combobox, a property from the selectedItem (which is actually a object with two properties - something like fieldname and value) populates the textbox.

Both controls are "hidden" within datatemplates and I am not sure how to populate one from the other??

Any ideas?  Much appreciated!!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a ContentConteol where content is bound to selected item of your listview - then the datetemplate should take care of displaying - I would set readonly on the textbox since altering the text will have no effect.

Comment: Ahh - I think I see your problem. I would add a SelectedItem property on your dataobject let it implement INotifyPropertyChanged and let the two controls bind to SelectedItem on your dataitem - in that way your selection is away from ui and the datatemplates is no problem.